# Remove extra adress info

Tags: koma-script, overleaf, letters, komacv

How can I remove the line below ? It is the underlined address field on the left, I don't want to repeat it 50 times, since it is already at the top right.

[image]

It was a template from here

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/letter-template-for-din-a4-english-and-german/cjxhrnbfrdrz

**EDIT**: Why the downvote ? I don't know much about TeX, use it only as a tool, no TeX-Expert. I found a primitive solution but it works

go to the link, then under "sender.lco" change the content in the `\setkomavar{backadress}{Sender Name, Example Street 123 D, 12345 ExampleCity}` to `\setkomavar{backadress}{}`, so basically remove the content in the last curly braces.

There is a "sender.lco" file in the folder, I don't know what it means but it is related to the main tex file, here is an excerpt of the code:

```
...

\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Telefon~]{+49\,123\,1234567}

\setkomavar{frommobilephone}[\Mobilefone~]{+49\,123\,1234567}

\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter~]{test@testmail.com}
%\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{http://test.de}

\setkomavar{backaddress}{Sender Name, Example Street 123 D, 12345 ExampleCity}

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Sender Name\\Example Street 123 D\\12345 ExampleCity}

...
```

I just deleted the 2nd last `\setkomavar` content, and it worked.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should more consider @DG' comment and provide what 
(s)he ask you. I'm very sure, that downvote will be nullify when you will in question provide MWE with what you try so far.

Comment: Welcome. // Your analysis and solution seem to be fine. Next time please provide code, which is ready for copy and compile, MWE, see above: you'll get better answers faster.

Comment: Use KOMA option backaddress=false to disable the return address above the address field.

Answer (score 3):

Use KOMA option `backaddress=false` to disable the return address above the address field:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sender.lco}
\ProvidesFile{sender.lco}[letter-class-option file]

\KOMAoptions{
  symbolicnames=marvosym,
  fromalign=right,
  fromemail=true,
  fromphone=true,
  frommobilephone=true
}

\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,123\,1234567}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{+49\,123\,1234567}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{test@testmail.com}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Sender Name}% <- added
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Example Street 123 D\\12345 ExampleCity}% <- changed

%\setkomafont{fromname}{\bfseries\LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small\rmfamily\slshape}
\setkomafont{addressee}{\small}

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\setplength{sigbeforevskip}{1.8cm}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\LoadLetterOption{sender}
\KOMAoptions{
  enlargefirstpage,
  backaddress=false% <- no return address above the address field
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\setparsizes{0pt}{3pt}{0pt plus 1fil}
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Appendix}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{% Set recipient of letter
      Recipient name \\
      Company SoUndSo\\
      What ever Street\\
      12345 ExampleCity
  }
  \setkomavar{subject}{Subject: This is an Example}
  \setkomavar{date}{den 14. November 2016}
  \setkomavar{place}{Bremen}
  \opening{Dear Recipient}

  \blindtext

  \selectlanguage{english}
  \blindtext

  \closing{Kind regards}
  \encl{annex}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

You can remove the `\setkomavar{backaddress}{...}` even if you want to use the return address. The content of variable `backaddress` is build from both variable `fromname` and `fromaddress` by default.

If you set variable `fromname` you can remove the `\setkomavar{signature}{...}` because `signature` uses `fromname` by default.